# Regular expression for replacing symbols

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

I'm writing an application that can execute different SQL statements(user specify these statements as one string value). I'm using ";" as delimeter between statements(at once user can execute many DML statements). But inside a DML statement there can be a varchar value that has ";" inside.

```
insert into A values(1, 'sda;asdad');
insert into A values(2, 'asdsa');
```

my first thought was to use `String#split(String regex)`. But I don't know how to make a regular expression that will help to split only by those semicolons that aren't inside varchars. Can you suggest one or maybe there is another approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a naive parser that might be what you're looking for.  I thought about using a regular expression.  At first I thought your language wasn't in fact, regular.

I believe DML is a Context Free Language, but really, your target language IS regular because you don't care about nested statements.  All you care about is detecting top-level strings.  But even that becomes a difficult to use a regex when you consider that there may possibly be escaped quotes inside your varchars.  i.e. 'abcd\'efg' of if you have multiple ; inside the varchar.

This code isn't pretty, but it should do what you're looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] ar) {
    String s = "aaa 'bb;bb;bb' aaa;  aaa 'bb;bb\\';bb' aaa";
    System.out.println(splitStatments(s, ';'));
}

private static List<String> splitStatments(String s, char statementDelimiter) {
    List<String> statements = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean outsideString = true;
    char lastChar = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        // in the case of the escaped \', we DON'T want to flip the boolean
        if (c == '\'' && lastChar != '\\') {
            outsideString = !outsideString;
        }
        if (c == statementDelimiter && outsideString) {
            statements.add(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuffer();
        } else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        lastChar = c;
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        statements.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return statements;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd solve this with escaping:

```
insert into A values(1, 'sda\\;asdad');
```

then when you `String#split()`, make sure that the `;` is not preceded by a `\` using a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Something like this:

```
String rawInput = ...;
String[] statements = rawInput.split("(?<!\\\\);");
```

Comment: it's a good idea but it will be better that user will not know about that semicolons have to be escaped, so he/she has to have input the sql string just like in Oracle SQL developer or PL/SQL developer

Comment: Without character escaping you're going to basically start writing a parser. Checking to see if a semicolon occurs within a string literal is nontrivial.

Answer (score 1):

The following is more complicated that `String.split`, but it works:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex2 {

   static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*'(.*);(.*)'.*");

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String target = "'asdf;asdf';";

      String[] split = split(target);
      if (split == null)
         System.out.println("No match");
      else
         for (String word : split(target))
            System.out.println(word);
   }

   static String[] split(String target) {
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(target);
      String[] split = null;
      if (matcher.matches()) {
         split = new String[matcher.groupCount()];
         for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++)
            split[i - 1] = matcher.group(i);
      }
      return split;
   }
}
```